# Cloud pages upsert help needed

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a form with a list of checkboxes and I want to upsert the ticked boxes to a DE in marketing cloud.

I have 2 problems. 
1) the record in the DE is being created twice 
2) the check boxes are not updating.

Here is the ampscript - i have xxed the redirect pages

```
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") =='submitted' THEN

 SET @Salutation = RequestParameter("Salutation")  
 SET @PersonEmail = RequestParameter("PersonEmail")
 SET @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
 SET @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
 SET @Interest = RequestParameter("Interest")
 SET @Country = RequestParameter("Countries")
 SET @Region = RequestParameter("Regions")
 SET @SourceFrom = RequestParameter("ExactTarget Source Form")
 SET @DonorType = RequestParameter("Donor/Organisation Record Type")
 SET @Ownership = RequestParameter("Ownership")
 SET @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account', 'Email_Address_Unique__c', 'Email_Address_Unique__c', '=', @PersonEmail)

/***Redirect for existing records or create new record in salesforce***/
IF @rs IS NOT NULL then Redirect("https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/xxx") 
ELSE
SET @_SFobjid = CreateSalesforceObject("Account",7,"Salutation",@Salutation,"FirstName",@FirstName,"LastName",@LastName,"Email_Address_Unique__c",@PersonEmail,"RecordTypeId",@DonorType,"ExactTarget_Source_Form__pc",@SourceFrom,"OwnerId",@Ownership)
ENDIF

/***Set Record Type***/

if "Account" == "Contact" then SET @_SFtype = "Contact" endif
if "Account" == "Lead" then SET @_SFtype = "Lead" endif

/*** Retrieve the Contact ID, that was created in order to set subscriber key for triggered send ***/

Set @CreatedRecord = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account', 'Email_Address_Unique__c,PersonContactID', 'Email_Address_Unique__c', '=', @PersonEmail)

IF RowCount(@CreatedRecord) > 0  then
SET @selectedRecord = Row(@CreatedRecord,1)
SET @subKey = Field(@selectedRecord,'PersonContactID')
ENDIF

/***Set Marketing Cloud DE values***/

 SET @Interest_water = false
 SET @Interest_food = false
 SET @Interest_war = false
 SET @Interest_emergency = false
 SET @Interest_registration = false
 SET @Interest_shelter = false
 SET @Interest_education = false
 SET @Interest_medicine = false
 SET @Interest_repatriationresettlement = false
 SET @Interest_nopreference = false
 SET @country_syria = false
 SET @country_south_sudan = false
 SET @country_somalia = false
 SET @country_afghanistan = false
 SET @country_iraq = false
 SET @country_yemen = false
 SET @country_nopreference = false
 SET @region_africa = false
 SET @region_americas = false
 SET @region_asiaPacific = false
 SET @region_europe = false
 SET @region_middleeast = false
 SET @region_nopreference = false

 /*** Set interests ***/
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"water") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_Water = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"food") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_Food = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"war") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_War = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"emergency") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_Emergency = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"registration") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_Registration = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"shelter") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_Shelter = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"education") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_Education = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"medicine") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_Medicine = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"Voluntary repatriation/Resettlement") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_RepatriationResettlement = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@interest,"no preference") > 0 THEN SET @Interest_NoPreference = true ENDIF

 /*** Set country ***/
 IF IndexOf(@country,"Syria") > 0 THEN SET @Country_Syria = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@country,"South Sudan") > 0 THEN SET @Country_South_Sudan = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@country,"Somalia") > 0 THEN SET @Country_Somalia = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@country,"Afghanistan") > 0 THEN SET @Country_Afghanistan = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@country,"Iraq") > 0 THEN SET @Country_Iraq = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@country,"Yemen") > 0 THEN SET @Country_Yemen = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@country,"No Preference") > 0 THEN SET @Country_NoPreference = true ENDIF

 /*** Set Region ***/
 IF IndexOf(@region,"Africa") > 0 THEN SET @Region_Africa = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@region,"Americas") > 0 THEN SET @Region_Americas = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@region,"Asia and the Pacific") > 0 THEN SET @Region_AsiaPacific = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@region,"Europe") > 0 THEN SET @Region_Europe = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@region,"Middle East and North") > 0 THEN SET @Region_MiddleEast = true ENDIF
 IF IndexOf(@region,"No Preference") > 0 THEN SET @Region_NoPreference = true ENDIF

UpsertData("HK_EN_eNEWS_Signup",1,"SubscriberKey",@SubKey,"EmailAddress",@PersonEmail,"Salutation",@salutation,"FirstName",@FirstName,"LastName",@LastName,"Interest_Water",@Interest_Water,"Interest_Food",@Interest_Food,"Interest_War",@Interest_War,"Interest_Emergency",@Interest_Emergency,"Interest_registration",@Interest_Registration,"Interest_Shelter",@Interest_Shelter,"Interest_Education",@Interest_Education,"Interest_Medicine",@Interest_Medicine,"Interest_RepatriationResettlement",@Interest_RepatriationResettlement,"Interest_NoPreference",@Interest_NoPreference,"Country_Syria",@Country_Syria,"Country_South_Sudan",@Country_South_Sudan,"Country_Somalia",@Country_Somalia,"Country_Afghanistan",@Country_Afghanistan,"Country_Iraq",@Country_Iraq,"Country_Yemen",@Country_Yemen,"Country_NoPreference",@Country_NoPreference,"Region_Africa",@Region_Africa,"Region_Americas",@Region_Americas,"Region_AsiaPacific",@Region_AsiaPacific,"Region_Europe",@Region_Europe,"Region_MiddleEast",@Region_MiddleEast,"Region_NoPreference",@Region_NoPreference)

 /*** Set Triggered Send Values ***/

 VAR @ts, @tsDef, @ts_sub, @ts_attr, @tsctr, @ts_subkey, @ts_statusCode, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode

 SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
 SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")

 SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "HK_EN_eNEWS_Signup")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

 SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", RequestParameter("PersonEmail"))

 IF NOT EMPTY(@subKey) THEN
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @subKey)
 ELSE
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", RequestParameter("PersonEmail"))
 ENDIF

 IF NOT IsNull(@Country) THEN
 SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "Country")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", @Country)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
 ENDIF

 IF NOT IsNull(@FirstName) THEN
 SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "FirstName")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", @FirstName)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
 ENDIF

 IF NOT IsNull(@LastName) THEN
 SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "LastName")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", @LastName)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
 ENDIF

 IF NOT IsNull(@DonorType) THEN
 SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "RecordTypeId")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", @DonorType)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
 ENDIF

 IF NOT IsNull(@SourceFrom) THEN
 SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "Source")
 SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", @SourceFrom)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
 ENDIF

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
 RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF

Redirect("https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/xxx")
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: hi @Data_Kid - yes they can have more than one interest, there is a list of checkboxes on the form which are supposed to update a boolean field from false to true

Comment: scratch the Caps theory just did a test and its fully case insensitive

Comment: @interest variable is a header on the form itself, i will remove that and see it it helps

Comment: or try printing it to see what its returning. same goes for coutries and the other check boxes

Comment: as to why its upserting twice my only guess is that one of the redirects might be to the same page, so the upsert fires twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasons for interests not populating, does the form have a interest attribute?

Reasons for 2 inserts into DE - there is a upsert statement and a triggered send ampscript api call which will both add records to the same DE.